# Get shared folder permissions

Tags: powershell

Im quite new with powershell and I need to do a shared folders permission  report. I've the following code:

```
$path = \\server\shared_folder
dir $path | where { $_.PsIsContainer } | % { $path1 = $_.fullname; Get-Acl $_.Fullname | % { $_.access | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty '.\Application Data' -Value $path1 -passthru }} | Export-Csv $reportpath
```

But the output is:

> \\server\shared_folder\folder1;FileSystemRights;AccessControlType;IsInherited;InheritanceFlags;PropagationFlags
>
> \\server\shared_folder\folder2;FileSystemRights;AccessControlType;IsInherited;InheritanceFlags;PropagationFlags

I need the following output:

> \\server\shared_folder;FileSystemRights;AccessControlType;IsInherited;InheritanceFlags;PropagationFlags

Why is doing the "dir" recursiveley if I do not specify it? If I am specifying where im telling to do so?

Answer (score 1):

To get the exact answer you are asking for:

```
$path = "\\server\shared_folder"
dir $path | where { $_.PsIsContainer } | % { $path1 = $_.Root; Get-Acl $_.Fullname | % { $_.access | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty '.\Application Data' -Value $path1 -passthru }} | Export-Csv $reportpath
```

Notice the "$_.Root" after the ForEach-Object (%). But in my opinion the following is better because this way you see the foldername under '.\Application Data':

```
$path = "\\server\shared_folder"
dir $path | where { $_.PsIsContainer } | % { $path1 = $_.Name; Get-Acl $_.Fullname | % { $_.access | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty '.\Application Data' -Value $path1 -passthru }} | Export-Csv $reportpath
```

Hope this helps, because your question is not very clear imo.

Comment: This output is better than mine. Thanks a lot!
Let me try to wirte a better explanation...Given a shares list, I need a report of each share permissions (overall groups and rights), but not the children folders...
Hope this explanation is clearer than first one...
Sorry about my English :(

Answer (score 0):

Also please do yourself a favour and write the code in PowerShell ISE and use the PowerShell StyleGuide guidelines:

```
$path = "\\server\shared_folder"
$shares = Get-ChildItem $path | Where-Object { $_.PsIsContainer }
$data = foreach($share in $shares){ 
    $path = $share.Name
    $acls = Get-Acl $share.Fullname 
    foreach($acl in $acls){ 
        $acl.access | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty '.\Application Data' -Value $path -passthru
    } 
} 
$data | Export-Csv $reportpath
```

This makes the code readable and makes it easier to troubleshoot or modify the code later on. This version does not output ChildItems of the folders inside the shared folder. Only the folders placed inside "\server\shared_folder".